# Часы на tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, время, datetime

Я пытался сделать **часы** на *tkinter*. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка:

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
win = tk.Tk()
win.title('Clock')
while True:
    time = (datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours = 5)).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    lbl_time = tk.Label(text = time)
    lbl_time.pack()
    lbl_time.destroy()
```

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант

```
from tkinter import Canvas, Tk, Frame, LAST
from time import strftime
from math import cos, sin, radians, pi

root = Tk()
root.title('Clock')
root.geometry('420x420')
root.config(bg='white')
root.minsize(width=420, height=420)

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

frame = Frame(root, height=400, width=400,  bg='black', relief='sunken')
frame.grid(column=0,row=0)

canvas = Canvas(frame, bg='black', width=385, height=385, relief='raised', bd=10)
canvas.grid(padx=5, pady=5)


def track_time(hr, mi, se):
    canvas.create_oval(
        50, 50, 350, 350, 
        fill='black', 
        outline='green2', 
        width=6, 
        activeoutline='dark violet', 
        activefill='gray12'
    )

    numbers = [11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 12]

    for i in range(0, len(numbers)):        
        canvas.create_text(
            200 - 120 * sin(((i+1)*2*pi)/12), 
            200 - 120 * cos(((i+1)*2*pi)/12), 
            text=numbers[i], 
            font=('Arial',12, 'bold'), 
            fill='white'
        )

    for y in range(60):
        canvas.create_text(
            200 - 140 * sin(((y+1)*2*pi)/60), 
            200 - 140 * cos(((y+1)*2*pi)/60), 
            text='•', 
            font=('Arial',12, 'bold'), 
            fill ='deep sky blue')

    for x in range(12):
        canvas.create_text(
            200 - 140 * sin(((x+1)*2*pi)/12), 
            200 - 140 * cos(((x+1)*2*pi)/12), 
            text='•', 
            font=('Arial',25, 'bold'), 
            fill ='red'
        )

    # по часовой стрелке часы, минуты, секунды
    canvas.create_line(
        200, 200, 
        200 + 60*sin(radians(hr)), 
        200 - 60*cos(radians(hr)), 
        fill='red',
        width=9,
        arrow= LAST
    )
    canvas.create_line(
        200, 200,
        200 + 80*sin(radians(mi)), 
        200 - 80*cos(radians(mi)), 
        fill='blue2',
        width=6,
        arrow= LAST
    )
    canvas.create_line(
        200, 200,
        200 + 120*sin(radians(se)), 
        200 - 120*cos(radians(se)), 
        fill='magenta2',
        width=3,
        arrow= LAST
    )
    
    canvas.create_oval(190, 190, 210, 210, fill='gold', outline='black', width=2)

def some_time():
    h = int(strftime('%H'))
    m = int(strftime('%M'))
    s = int(strftime('%S'))

    hr = (h / 12) * 360
    mi = (m / 60) * 360
    se = (s / 60) * 360

    track_time(hr, mi, se)
    canvas.after(1000, some_time)

some_time()
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Wow красиво! На Tk не ожидал XD

Comment: @VictorVosMottor полезно ? :)

Comment: Весьма (плюс сразу забыл поставить, чего-то давно на ruSO ниче делаю XD)

Answer (score 0):

**Ваши ошибки:**

1. Вы не запускаете основной цикл окна. Необходимо запустить окно, чтобы оно активировалось. Для этого надо написать `win.mainloop()` в конце кода
2. Из-за `win.mainloop()` у вас не будет активироваться цикл `while True`, поэтому нужно сделать дополнительный процесс, который будет выполняться параллельно `win.mainloop()`. Для этого будем использовать модель `threading`
3. В цикле вы постоянно убираете и создаете надпись. Так ее совсем не будет видно. Лучше создать надпись, а потом обновлять текст в этой надписи.

Наша функция после таких поправок будет выглядеть так:

```python
lbl_time = tk.Label()  # Заранее создаем надпись, которую будем менять
lbl_time.pack()

def clock_update():
    # Меняем text у нашей надписи
    lbl_time["text"] = (datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours = 5)).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

**Итого весь код будет таким:**

```python
import threading  # Импортируем модель для дополнительных процессов
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

win = tk.Tk()  # создаем окно
win.title('Clock')
time = (datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours = 5)).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
lbl_time = tk.Label(text = time)  # заранее создаем надпись
lbl_time.pack()  # размещаем ее
def clock_update():  # создаем функцию
    while True:
        # Постоянно меняем значение у наших часов
        lbl_time['text'] = (datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours = 5)).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        sleep(0.5)  # засыпаем на половину секунды, чтобы не перегружать процесс постоянными обновлениями

process = threading.Thread(target=clock_update)  # Создаем процесс, в котором будем обновлять наши часы
process.start()  # Запускаем процесс

win.mainloop()  # Активируем окно
```

Вот результат (часы меняются)

[image: Часы]